# Custom javascript file not working in mobile browsers

Tags: theming, 8

I have added a custom jQuery file to my theme with the theme.libraries.yml. In my laptop and fullscreen browsers the added javascript is working without any issues. But it seems the javascript does not have any effect in mobile browsers(I'm testing with ipad and iphone browsers in both safari and chrome). My custom_theme_libraries.yml is as following

```
global-scripts:
  js:
  js/jqueryfile1.js: {}
dependencies:
- core/jquery
```

And my jqueryfile1.js is as following

```
(function ($){
Drupal.behaviors.myModuleBehavior = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
        $(document).ready(function(){

            //code goes here

            });
        });
    }
};
})(jQuery);
```

Is there any additional configurations to be considered to get the code works in mobile browser also?

Comment: No - JavaScript is JavaScript, if the file is in the source then the code will be executed, there's no mobile v non-mobile distinction unless your JS code checks the viewport/user agent. You can easily tell by adding test code, e.g. an alert, at the top of the file. By the by, the use of `ready` is redundant, behaviours are already delayed until DOM ready

Comment: Yes, the difference is not mobile, probably logged in or not. The error could be the missing spaces before the dependencies in the yaml file.

Comment: Thanks i will take these into consideration and and will update you the result soon

Comment: You don't need to add document ready, that is redundant within a behavior.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like your code is the problem. You have extra `});`

Should be

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.myModuleBehavior = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
      $(document).ready(function() {
        // code goes here
      });
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

But it is nonsense to use `$(document).ready` as it is already handled by `Drupal.behaviors`.

So the proper way is.

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.myModuleBehavior = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
      // code goes here
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

The `attach()` method is called when the DOM has loaded both initially and after any AJAX calls.

See this doc for more info. https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview